# Android NDK: How to use NDK_APP_OUT

Tags: android-ndk

I am have a project with multiple dependencies, I want to isolate each one for reusability. I can't, however, figure out how to control the location of the libs and obj folders. Here is what I tried...

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := box2D
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/.. $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
NDK_APP_OUT :=../../
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    $(subst $(LOCAL_PATH)/,, \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/Collision/*.cpp) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/Collision/Shapes/*.cpp) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/Rope/*.cpp) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/Dynamics/*.cpp) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/Dynamics/Contacts/*.cpp) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/Dynamics/Joints/*.cpp) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/Common/*.cpp))
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lm -llog -ldl
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But this still puts the libs and obj in the ./ folder. How do I have the make file move them two directories back?

**Update**

Also tried NDK_OUT :=../../

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/fddbYMAS_GQ

Comment: So Application.mk not Android.mk huh? I will try in a sec

Comment: did you manage to solve this?